# Div fluid with float elements

Tags: html, css

Look at the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/B2wFZ/ 

If your resolution is 1366x768 you will see the input in line with the text, try zooming out, the input is no longer in line with the text. How to make sure that the div widens if necessary with min-width? Now if I replace:

```
width: 350px;
```

with

```
min-width: 350px;
```

the width becomes 100%. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use min-width and apply one of the following propperties which will cause the div to "shrink wrap" to the minimum width:

```
display:inline-block;
display:table;
float:left;
display:table-cell;
```

there may be more.

I chose float left, but others are fine too, especially if you wish to center the div.

Here a demo:
http://jsfiddle.net/m5UYx/

Answer (score 0):

How about floating the left div with width of 60% for example, and the right one can have width of 40%, and the input inside can have width 100% to take the full width of the div.

Or you can float the left div and give the second one:

```
.input { position: relative; overflow: hidden; }
```

[Here is a an example](http://jsfiddle.net/B2wFZ/2/)